# Bug in displaying the list of review badges

Tags: support, bug, review, badges

Badges such as "Custodian" (bronze) to "Steward" (gold) are awarded for each of the six review types. However, in browsing the list of users who have been awarded a badge, CV reports the same users in the same order with the same time and date of their award.

To me, it looks like -- across all 6 review types -- that the "First Post" badge information is being reported for all. Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't understand your question. For custodian & reviewer, there are 7 types; for steward, there are 6 types. If I go to badges > custodian & then scroll to the [end](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/109?page=32), I don't see what you're saying.

Comment: From CV -- not Meta -- if you click on "review" in the upper right, it will take you to a screen that displays the current status of the review types -- "First Posts," "Late Answers," etc. For each type, there's a button for "recent reviews >"  If you click on that button for each review type and then click, e.g., on the "gold" badge for "Steward" to display the information about how many times that badge has been awarded, who's received it and when, the information displayed is the same for all of the review types...at least on my screens.

Comment: @gung  You are correct but I'm not as senior as you guys so I can view only 4 types...

Comment: So, if you go to reviews > recent reviews [first posts] > steward, you see the same thing as if you go to reviews > recent reviews [late answers] > steward. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly...again, on my screens. You guys may have different information displayed as a function of your status.

Comment: -1 because there is clearly no bug: it's just that you land on the same page whether you go through e.g. "first posts" or "late answers". Even the url is the same. And this page does indicate who got the steward badge for what.

Comment: @amoeba  It's possible to disagree on this. If the badges are tracked and tallied separately for each type of badge, then it makes sense that the summaries should be separate for each type of badge. Call it what you will -- a bug, a conflation, a blurred summary -- but it's clearly not "no bug."

Comment: You could make a [feature-request] suggesting to display these tags separately for each type of review task. This might make sense, I have no opinion on that. But this would be a *feature request*, not a bug report. You wrote that it is a bug because "it looks like -- across all 4 review types -- that the "First Post" badge information is being reported for all." If this were true then indeed it would be a bug. But as the screenshot posted by @whuber clearly shows, for each badge award one can see what type of review it was awarded for! Some are for First Posts but some are not. So no bug.

Answer (score 5):

The list of *awards* (not awardees) for, say, the "Steward" badge appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/110/steward .  Awards are listed in reverse chronological order.  Individuals may be awarded the badge multiple times.  Each such award will be listed according to the time it was made.  Here is an excerpt showing multiple awards:

[image: Figure]

There are various ways to link to this summary, including through each type of review listed in the review stats pages, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats and https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats.

No additional filter is being applied according to where one links from: you will land on the same page regardless.